# MongoDB Find values passed in that don't match

Tags: mongodb

Currently stuck with an issue using MongoDB aggregation. I have a array of '_ids' that I need to check exist in a specific collection.

Example:

I have 3 records in 'Collection 1' with _id 1,2,3. I can find the matching values using:

```
$match: {
    _id: {
        $in: [1, 2, 3, 4]
    }
}
```

However what I want to know is from the values I have passed in (1,2,3,4). Which ones don't match up to a record. (In this case _id 4 will not have a matching record)

So instead of returning records with _id 1, 2, 3. It needs to return the _id that doesn't exist. So in this example  '_id: 4'

The query should also disregard any extra records in the collection. Example, if the collection held records with ID 1-10, and I passed in a query to determine if the _ids:  1, 7, 15 existed. The the value i'm expecting would be along the lines of ' _id: 15 doesn't exist

The first thought was to use to use $project within a aggregation to hold each _id that was passed in, and then attach each record in the collection. To the matching _id passed in. E.g:

```
Record 1:

{
    _id: 1,
    Collection1: [
        record details: ...,
        ...
        ...

    ]
},
{
    _id: 2,
    Collection1: [] // This _id passed in, doesn't have a matching collection
}
```

However cant seem to get a working example in this instance. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the input documents are:

```
{ _id: 1 },
{ _id: 2 },
{ _id: 5 },
{ _id: 10 }
```

And the array to match is:

```
var INPUT_ARRAY = [ 1, 7, 15 ]
```

The following aggregation:

```
db.test.aggregate( [
{
  $match: {
    _id: {
        $in: INPUT_ARRAY
    }
  }
},
{ 
  $group: { 
      _id: null, 
      matches: { $push: "$_id" } 
  } 
},
{ 
  $project: {
      ids_not_exist: { $setDifference: [ INPUT_ARRAY, "$matches" ] },
      _id: 0
  } 
}
] )
```

Returns:

```
{ "ids_not_exist" : [ 7, 15 ] }
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for $not ?
[MDB Docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/not/)

Comment: Similar! However $not wont tell me what records don't exist. It'll show me the records that exist, but don't match my criteria